# Ubuntu 20.04 hangs even if nomodeset?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I haven't been using my Ubuntu partition in like two weeks. Coming back to it I do as per usual a package upgrade which, if I remember correctly may have been included some new nvidia packages too. After rebooting, the system completely hangs after the new boot.

What I've already tried with no success:

- Using `nomodeset` to verify driver issues. The system starts but after few seconds hangs again. It appears to be related to the graphic driver section since I can type, log into it and type commands inside the terminal (even if I see the same login page since I'm doing it by memory). Even changing the log level or using the tty2 console hangs right after.
- Using the Ubuntu recovery mode. This hangs aswell after few seconds.
- Running a `fsdisk` to check on filesystem corruption but no problems outlined.
- Changing the init system from the GRUB menu (`init=/bin/sh`). This is the only way I can interact with the system but changing the init system I have quite some limitations. If I could only connect to internet I could try removing the nvidia packages and maybe reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` or whatever but I don't know how to start a new network from there.

If you need more info I'm glad to give it to you. I'd rather find a fix for this (which appears to be really stupid but still...) then reinstalling the OS.

Answer (score 0):

So, after digging a bit deeper it was as presumed a video driver issue. The latest nvidia driver installation (`nvidia-driver-470`) was corrupted and made the system hang during boot time. I still can't figure out how the nomodeset was making the video output freeze but anyway..

What I did was booting in "safe mode" adding `init=/bin/sh` and changing `ro` to `rw` to the GRUB script and then manually removing the corrupted drivers:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
```

Some say that the `nvidia-common` package has dependencies with `ubuntu-desktop` but this wasn't my case. Otherwise, before proceeding it is highly advisable to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`.

After rebooting the nouveau driver should automatically take place. To be sure that nouveau will be load in boot, I forceed-load it by add it to /etc/modules and removed (comment out) the nvidia modules:

```
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Last, removing the Xorg config file aswell:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

After rebooting I could use the GUI again and reinstall correctly the latest nvidia drivers from the Software & Updates window.